# Curved Line (Bezier) Gradient

Tags: c#, wpf

How to draw a bezier with two colors? like the picture below?
I already have drawn the bezier, I can fill it with any color, however I cant the gradient working.

this is what im doing, im using a Path to create the bezier by the way.

```
    private void test()
    {
        System.Windows.Media.GradientStop GradientStop1 = new System.Windows.Media.GradientStop();
        System.Windows.Media.GradientStop GradientStop2 = new System.Windows.Media.GradientStop();
        System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush p_Fill; p_Fill = new System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Blue, Colors.Red, new Point(0, 0.5), new Point(1, 0.5));
        p_Fill.GradientStops.Add(GradientStop1);
        p_Fill.GradientStops.Add(GradientStop2);
        Bez.Fill = p_Fill;
    }
```

This is how it should be

[image]

This is what I get

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a sharp cut between the 2 colored halves, you have to need more `GradientStops`:

```
var grad3 = new System.Windows.Media.GradientStop() 
                  {Offset = 0.5, Color=Colors.Blue};
var grad4 = new System.Windows.Media.GradientStop() 
                  {Offset = 0.5, Color=Colors.Red};
GradientStop2.Offset = 1;
p_Fill.GradientStops.Add(GradientStop1);   
p_Fill.GradientStops.Add(grad3);
p_Fill.GradientStops.Add(grad4);
p_Fill.GradientStops.Add(GradientStop2);
```

Addtionally, you have to set the `Brush` for the `Stroke`, not the `Fill`. The `StrokeThickness` determines the thickness of the curve:

```
Bez.Stroke = p_Fill;
Bez.StrokeThickness = new Thickness(10);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, however i still have the problem above, it is not one proper line like above.

Comment: @Joe the last gradientstop (`GradientStop2`) should have `Offset` explicitly set to `1`.

Comment: @Joe just updated the answer, you should use `Stroke` instead of `Fill`.

Comment: Man i feel so stupid for using fill instead of stroke, that fixed the line problem which was my main problem, the gradient is still screwed up though, thank you so much.

Comment: @Joe not sure what's still wrong with it, on my side it just looks great (see screenshot). Also you may want to post your current result.

Comment: it is getting there, but the color separation is not in the middle, http://s29.postimg.org/mw38qtc53/bez3.png

Comment: That is fixed too, setting the offset of 1 and 2 to 0.1, thanks again.